# Concatenate only selected elements in a string in c++

Tags: c++

I thought this would be easy but I was really wondering can we concatenate selected individual elements in a string?

For example, given

```
string s = "Hello";
```

I want to concatenate `s[1]`, the length of the whole string `s`, and `s[4]`; the expected output is `e5o`.

Comment: You could use `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could do

```
std::string x = s[1] + std::to_string(s.size()) + s[4];
```

Comment: yeah, I already saw that example on the internet, any way of doing that without using library function?

Comment: Which library function do you want to avoid? And why?

Comment: i meant any other way without using to_string?

Comment: You could do something like `s.size() + '0'`, but that would only work for sizes less than 10. Again though, why do you want to do this without `to_string`?

Comment: i just want to learn to do that in as many different ways as possible. Anyway, Thanks. It was really helpful.

Comment: Sure thing. If you're happy with the answer, consider accepting it.